# How to rotate an image that needs cover fitting?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need an image to have both a `background-size: cover` and a `transform: rotate`.

The problem is that the cover fitting seems to be calculated before the transform. 
Therefore the image (not square) is rotated at the end, and the covering is not... fitting.

Is there a way to rotate it beforehand client side so the cover works well?
Or do I need necessarily to process the image server side for this?

Thx.

Here is an example:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
  const url_image = 'https://i.imgur.com/QmuBSqb.jpg';
  const image = document.getElementById("recording-img");
  fetch(url_image)
    .then(response => {
      if(response.ok) {
        response.blob().then(function(img_data) {
          const object_url = URL.createObjectURL(img_data);
          image.style.backgroundImage = `url('${object_url}')`;
          // Comment me to see how covering is expected:
          image.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';
        });
      }
    });
});
```

```css
html,body,#main,#recording-img {
  height: 100%;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
}

.empty-cols {
  flex: 0.175;
}

#center { 
  flex: 0.65;
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#recording-img {
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="empty-cols"></div>
    <div id="center">
      <div id="recording-img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="empty-cols"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

if you remove the last js line (transform rotate), you see that the image fits the parent div (shadow reveals it).

For my need, I have to get the image using javascript, and javascript will decide if the image needs to be rotated (based on exif).

Comment: You probably need the image to be in its own tag. You can then use `object-fit`. Can you share your code?

Comment: The transform applies to the container, not the background itself. So this is more an issue of the element not fitting where you would like it, the background just highlights it. It's unlikely we'll be able to help without a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have added an example as requested.